# How do I Update Only a Few Rows at a Time? (Multiple-Table Syntax)

Tags: mysql

Is there a way without using a script to run an UPDATE that won't slow the DB by only doing a certain amount of rows at a time?

I'm performing

```
UPDATE .. SET .. FROM .. INNER JOIN .. ON ... WHERE
```

and it's going to update 3,171 rows in a very large table.

I don't want to lock the DB or slow it down. Any ideas?

NOTE:

As per the MySQL docs for UPDATE: For the multiple-table syntax, UPDATE updates rows in each table named in table_references that satisfy the conditions. In this case, ORDER BY and LIMIT cannot be used.

I was performing an INNER JOIN and LIMIT was not allowed to be used, using LIMIT as a solution does not work in this case.

Comment: UPDATE queries can have a limit clause, but you'll have to be careful to exclude any previously updated rows if you're doing "relative" adjustments of fields.

Comment: @Marc As per the MySQL docs for UPDATE:

For the multiple-table syntax, UPDATE updates rows in each table named in
table_references that satisfy the conditions. In this case, ORDER BY and LIMIT
cannot be used.

Comment: Can you post the query you are using? The multi-table syntax for `UPDATE` does not allow `LIMIT`. But sometimes it's possible to convert the Update to the single-table syntax (pushing the Joins into the `WHERE` conditions.)

Comment: @KRB: Are your tables using MyISAM or InnoDB engine?

Comment: No need to add "MySQL" to the title. It's in the tags.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Believe it or not, you can use `LIMIT`!

```
UPDATE mytable SET ... WHERE ... LIMIT 10;
```

I know it sounds weird, and it is non-deterministic, but it's so handy!

#### Edit

However, for updating *joins*, limit is *not* supported. However, there is an solution!

Use variable to control how many rows are updated. Here's a general look at how it works:

```
set @i := 0;
update table1 t1
join table2 t2 on t1.keycol = t2.keycol and (@i := @i + 1) < 100
where t1.col != 'someval'
set t1.col = 'someval';
```

Here I'm updating the first/next 100 rows that match the join criteria - you can set it to whatever number you like.

Comment: As per the MySQL docs for UPDATE:

For the multiple-table syntax, UPDATE updates rows in each table named in
table_references that satisfy the conditions. In this case, ORDER BY and LIMIT
cannot be used.

Comment: See "multiple-table syntax". User error: replace and try again

Comment: @KRB OK - You were right about multi-table limit not being supported. However, I have worked out a solution for how to do a limit with joins! See edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

If possible you could first select the ID's of the rows that you will be updating, then run the update query on this subset of ID's

```
Update tbl set MyKey = 'Updated' where ID between 1000 AND 2000
```

Answer (score 1):

See here for low priority updates:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_low_priority_updates

Comment: You should mention that `UPDATE LOW PRIORITY` affects only MyISAM and MEMORY tables, not InnoDB.